# Changing Emacs font color

Tags: emacs, themes, elisp, emacs-faces

I'm a bit of an emacs noob.

I'm completely satisfied with `tomorrow-night-bright-theme` except the fluorescent one below

[image: i hate that color]

I'v read some articles explaining how to change font faces in Emacs.

[1. Changing highlight line color in emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701576/changing-highlight-line-color-in-emacs)
[2. Change Emacs syntax highlighting colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076503/change-emacs-syntax-highlighting-colors)

However, I don't know what symbol is related to that color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try <kbd>M-x</kbd> `list-faces-display` <kbd>RET</kbd>. This will bring up a list of all defined faces, I guess you could easily spot the fluorescent one there.

Answer (score 5):

My usual approach is to move point to the text in question and type <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> which nowadays runs the command `what-cursor-position` with the DETAIL argument set, which tends to give you all the information you want on that text, including the faces involved, which are linked through to their details and customize interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

M-x color-theme-print will give you a printed representation of the current colour theme and the lisp that you need to install it. Combined with list-faces-display it will solve your problem!